# fileId isn't looping properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, amazon-s3, axios

Quick explanation of this block: I have a `files` object, which is all the files I'm uploading, then I have a `signedUrls` object which has all of the signed URLs from an earlier S3 function. The objects have matching indexes.

The first `axios.put` uploads the file, and the second `axios.post` saves the file key to my DB. (I don't want to save it to my DB unless it was uploaded successfully, hence the `axios.post`'s location in the callback.)

The files are uploading just fine, but the `fileId` isn't looping properly and typically saves the same `fileId` over and over again. I.e., if I upload five files, they'll upload to S3, but they'll all have the same id in my DB. Ideas why this is happening?

```
fileIds = {"1": "someFileId", "2": "someOtherId" }    

for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  axios.put(signedUrls[i], files[i], config).then(res => {
    axios.post('https://myapi.com/add-file', {
      fileId: fileIds[i]
    }).then(res => {
      // success
    });
```

Comment: Try adding `const id = fileId` inside the loop and use that instead of `fileId`. Or at least show us where it's assigned.

Comment: @destoryer see my edit - it works something like this where the file ids are also an object with numbered keys. I over-simplified my original post.

Comment: Everything seems ok to me.

Comment: Are you running this code in node.js or in a browser? Using `axios` and a separate `post` call to save data to DB look suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're doing an async call inside of a synchronous `for` loop.

By the time the `post` request is invoked, your loop has already finished.

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to solve this:

```
const promises = files.map((file, i) => {

  // create a new promise with correct index, but don't call it yet
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return axios.put(signedUrls[i], file, config)
    .then(res => {
      return axios.post('https://myapi.com/add-file', {
        fileId: fileIds[i]
      }).then(res => {
        resolve(res)
        // todo: also handle errors here
      })
    })
  })

})

// actually invoke your calls here
Promise.all(promises).then(res => /* success */ )
```

Essentially, what you'll be doing is creating your promise calls synchronously (but not actually calling them yet) so that you can use the correct indexes, and then you'll use `Promise.all` to actually invoke the array of promises.

Comment: Downvoting - why use `Promise.all` if each promise acts for itself and there is no action afterwards?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `i` is bound to the same value in your `.post` section.
To fix this - you could use a self executed anonymous function.
Like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    axios.put(signedUrls[i], files[i], config).then(res => {
      axios.post('https://myapi.com/add-file', {
        fileId: fileIds[i]
      }).then(res => {
        // success
      });
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: You can't send a number by reference in JavaScript.

Comment: @destoryer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: If you actually read the answers to the question, I'm sure you'd find that using `let` actually scopes the variable to each iteration.

Comment: @destoryer If you actually read the answers to the question, I'm sure you'd find that using `let` in IE9-IE11 and Edge prior to Edge 14 will not help.

Comment: I appreciate the information, I had no idea Edge failed to implement correcly. In either case, the op is using node, not IE.